# How do I modify the host file on a Genymotion VM from windows?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualhost, genymotion

I'm basically trying to simplify my development workflow a bit. I have a azure mobile services project running inside IIS on my windows host machine, which I can connect to from the Genymotion Android VM using an IP address (10.71.34.1).

What I'd like to be able to do is connect to the mobile services website using a host header (e.g. http://devmobservices rather than http://10.71.34.1:12345).

How can I modify the host file opn the Genymotion VM to allow me to do this?

(Also, if there's a better solution then please point me at that!)

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To modify the host file, you need first to mount the `system` partition in read-write.

After launching your Genymotion device, open a command line and type:

```
adb shell
mount -o remount,rw /system
echo "10.71.34.1   devmobservices" >> /etc/hosts
```

After that you will be able to reach your service through `http://devmobservices:1234` address.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the prior commenters for their assistance. Note that the location of adb is different on OS-X, so the actual commands would be:

```
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/adb shell

mount -o remount,rw /system

echo "10.71.34.1   devmobservices" >> /etc/hosts
```

Also, be sure the VM you want to modify is first running before entering the first command.